# how can i add another new ip to my ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, ip

i got a new IP for my server from my host. the server is already hosting one site.

i got a range of IP. like 23.23.23.23~23.23.23.27

how can i add these ?

Answer (score 3):

You update your `/etc/network/interfaces` file.  Something like this is probably close to what you want.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 23.23.23.23
    netmask 255.255.255.192
    gateway 23.23.23.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2
    dns-search example.com
    # add secondary ip address
    up ip addr add 23.23.23.27/26 brd + dev eth0
    down ip addr del 23.23.23.27/26 brd + dev eth0
```

Answer (score 2):

Beneath your regular iface lines for your default interface, add:

```
up ip addr add 23.23.23.23/32 dev eth0
up ip addr add 23.23.23.24/32 dev eth0
up ip addr add 23.23.23.25/32 dev eth0
up ip addr add 23.23.23.26/32 dev eth0
up ip addr add 23.23.23.27/32 dev eth0
```

This will add each IP individually.

Alternatively you can add the network via CIDR in one line:

```
up ip addr add 23.23.23.24/29 dev eth0
```

Both will work if the network was added as a proper CIDR network.

Answer (score 0):

You could create some ethernet aliases, like this:

```
ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.0.1/24
ifconfig eth0:2 192.168.0.2/24
ifconfig eth0:3 192.168.0.3/24
ifconfig eth0:4 192.168.0.4/24
```